# How to migrate project in PeopleSoft if connect id password is different?

Tags: peoplesoft

To migrate a project from one environment to another in PeopleSoft using Application Designer Connect Id credentials(default is people/peop1e) must be same in both environment.

Is there any way we can migrate projects if connect id and password are different in both the environment.

Answer (score 3):

You could copy the project to a file between environments:

1. Save the project to a file from the source environment
2. Change the connect information in Configuration Manager
3. Copy the project from a file in the destination environment

Or it looks like you could you use App Designer Command Line parameters to copy the project from one database to another with different connect passwords but I haven't tried it.  Here is the PeopleBooks page for [Understanding PeopleSoft Application Designer Command Line Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58500_01/pt854pbh1/eng/pt/tlcm/concept_UnderstandingPeopleSoftApplicationDesignerCommandLineParameters-07741f.html#topofpage) and the [Command Line Parameter Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58500_01/pt854pbh1/eng/pt/tlcm/concept_CommandLineParameters.html#topofpage)